# Pandas DataFrame updating Column values with other DataFrame

Tags: pandas

Consider the following DataFrame X:

```
Col A Col B 
1     2
3     4
5     6
```

And the DataFrame Y:

```
Col A Col B 
3     7
8     9
```

Does there exist a built in function in pandas that will Combine the two dataframes, using Col A as keys and updating value in Col B if it exists, otherwise append. Such that the output of this function on X and Y is

```
Col A Col B
1     2
3     7
5     6
8     9
```

I've looked into merge and update and append but they don't seem to act the way I want, update updates by index instead of Col A value, merge doesn't overwrite, ect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) then [drop the duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.concat([dfX, dfY])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   ColA  ColB
0     1     2
1     3     4
2     5     6
0     3     7
1     8     9

In [13]: df.drop_duplicates(cols=['ColA'], take_last=True)
Out[13]:
   ColA  ColB
0     1     2
2     5     6
0     3     7
1     8     9
```

*Note: the `take_last` argument means you are "updating from dfY".*

Comment: Note2: Interestingly in ubutbu's (deleted) answer he uses `combine_first` (but found it to be twice as slow as this method).